# Overlay Image on Live Camera feed using Wikitude

Tags: android, overlay, augmented-reality, wikitude

I have gone through all the samples of wikitude. Is it possible to overlay live camera feed image which has been saved as screenshot and create augmenetd image? If it is possible then what tracker image should I use? Because tracker image is the one which I know presently that which image I am going for track. Then if the image will be taken in future how can I create a .wtc file for that and how can I augment my camera feed? Is it possible in wikitude?

I have to create one application using wikitude. I like the sdk of wikitude.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for a way to create target images (that are used for recognition) on the device. This is currently not supported. However if you have a valid business case we are able to provide you with a server based tool to create target images. For more information please contact sales@wikitude.com.

Disclaimer: As you probably already guessed, I'm working for Wikitude.